# Spriting Animation Method

Tags: animation, cocos2d-x

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/539087245/spriter

At 3:00 they discuss that there is a method used to separate the parts of character into individual sprites and move them saving production time and video memory. What is this method called I am thinking that I want to implement it for my game but need to do more research.
Thanks alot =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called 2D skeletal animation. Essentially you're animating a skeleton that has sprites for the body parts placed on top of it. This allows you to reuse animations for different characters and characters can have multiple sets of armor, weapons, etc.

There are a number of questions on the site already about it:

[Tools for 2D skeletal animation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22000/tools-for-2d-skeletal-animation)

[How Plants vs Zombies animation is done?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/how-plants-vs-zombies-animation-is-done)

[Tips on combining the right Art Assets with a 2D Skeleton and making it flexible](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24695/tips-on-combining-the-right-art-assets-with-a-2d-skeleton-and-making-it-flexible)

And some other good resources:

http://www.catalinzima.com/2011/06/2d-skeletal-animations/

http://www.thecareergamer.com/braaaains-zombieville-usa-tech-review/

Enjoy your research.